# Namenode is not showing in JPS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

Namenode is not working

When I run the command start-all.sh it says running namenode[localhost] But when I run JPS command namenode is not showing. Everytime I have to run hadoop namenode -format in order to run namenode,is their any other solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to find and provide us your namenode logs